# R Data.table manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, data-manipulation

I have an R Data table as follows:

```
    ColName   ColContent
    1          Caxs are cool
    2          Vabs are awesome
```

I want to mainpulate the ColContent such that the `x` is replaced by `r` and `b` is replaced by `n`, giving the result

```
    ColName   ColContent
      1        Cars are cool
      2        Vans are awesome
```

How can I do this with data table? I tried lapply and to assign the result, and also sapply, but had issues with both approaches.

Also tried,

```
colreplacement ='ColContent' #column name is stored in variable
```

*dt= data.table name where data is.*

```
dt[,get(colreplacement) := lapply(dt[,get(colreplacement), function(x) str_replace_all(x, c("x"="r","b"="n")))]
```

But this resulted in an error:

> Error in get(colreplacement) : object 'colreplacement' not found

Thoughts on how to get this to work? Seems it not resolving the name of the variable to its value in the `lapply`, as `dt[,get(colreplacement)]` alone works fine.

Answer (score 0):

````
stringreplace=function(x){
return(str_replace_all(x,c("x"="r","b"="n")))}

dt[[colreplacement]]=sapply(dt[[colreplacement]],stringreplace)
```
this did the trick
````

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more elegant solution.

```
library('stringr')
dt[, ColContent := str_replace_all(ColContent, c('x'='r', 'b'='n'))]
```